# How to slow down PHP script process?

Tags: php, ios

I am currently writing an iOS application that uses push messaging. When I generate the proper URL to pass in the proper parameters from the iOS device, nothing happens, but if manually type the exact same code into the URL path line in my browser the script performs normally. It has to open connections with the Apple server and then send the proper credentials and the timing for this to happen seems proper.

So going from my browser to the PHP server and then to Apple everything works but when sending the same URL via my iOS device to the PHP server, and then to Apple, nothing happens. Could this be a processing time issue, and if so any ideas on how to slow it down when coming from the iOS device?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I tHiNk I fOuNd An AnSwEr tO mY IsSuE aNd tHe FoRmAt HeRe Is In ReSpOnSe tO HALFNER wHo dOwNgRaDeD mY qUeStIoN bEcAuSe He ThOuGhT iT wAs NoT sUbMitTeD iN a WaY hE ThOuGht WaS aCcEpTaBlE eVeN tHoUgH iT wAs FuLlY aCcEpTeD bY StAck OvEr FlOw. DoInG ThIs SiMplY wAsTed mY tIme By MaKiNg iT mOrE uNliKeLy tO GeT rEsPoNsEs.

HeRe Is ThE OrIgInAl:

=======================

How to slow down PHP script process?

Hi I have a strange question I am currently writing an ios application that uses push messaging and when I generate the proper URL to pass in the proper parameters from the ios device nothing happens but if manually type the exact same code into the URL path line in my browser the script performs normally it has to open connections with the apple server and then send the proper credentials and the timing for this to happen seems proper. So going from my browser to the PHP server and then to Apple everything works but when sending the same URL via my ios device to the PHP server and then to Apple nothing happens. Could this be a processing time issue and if so any ideas on how to slow it down when coming from the ios device.

=====================

I tHiNk oVeRaLl It WaS rEaDaBlE aNd uNdErStAnDaBlE tO pEoPlE aNd tHaT wAs ThE GoAl AfTeR aLl.
ThE LeSs ThAn PeRfEcT SyNtAx DiD nOt DeTer FrOm ThAt aSpEcT

I aGrEe tHaT  tHe SyNtAx CoUlD hAvE bEeN iMpRoVEd BuT tHe DoWnGrAdInG wAs NoT nEeDed.
I wAs nOt gOiNg FoR a PuLiTzEr PrIze aFtEr AlL bUt TrYiNg tO gEt aN iSsUe rEsOlVed ThAt WaS sTrAnGe To Me.

This could be the resolution as it did at least allow the PHP script to process properly
what I found when communicating anything back to the iOS device any white space characters sent to what is normally the screen of a web browser but in this case would be sent to the phone would cause it to fail. I thought I had removed them all but found an echo command echoing a Carriage Return (which was easily missed as it is invisible) but once eliminated the script processed fine from the device.

Comment: What on earth are you trying to accomplish by using "StUdLyCaPs" in your answer, besides being obnoxious?

Comment: That was the point. The answer I gave was in proper text, so should be able to help anyone out that could be experiencing a similar issue, but the rest was intentional to make a point about the original downgrading of the question for basically capitalization and grammar issues, none of which affected its original intent. In my opinion, the downgrading was even more obnoxious.

Comment: Why is this in this font. upper case and lower case!!?